# 19 hrs layover in Frankfurt. Have US and Canada valid visa . Can go out of airport without transit visa

Tags: schengen, transit, indian-citizens, canada, frankfurt

Do i require a transit visa during my 19 hr layover in Frankfurt? Travelling with family to Toronto. Having valid US Visa also. We are Indian family.

- Can we go out of Airport during long layover and if yes do i require transit visa for it or not? Or just hotel booking will help us getting shore pass like that given in Japan?
- Secondly if we don't go out what are options on airport for 19 hrs layover?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the linked duplicate question, your visa for Canada exempts you from the requirement to hold a transit visa.  However, you cannot leave the international zone of the airport unless you hold a regular (type C) Schengen visit visa.

The legislation creating the transit visa exemption is [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20200202) Article 3(5)(c):

> 5. The following categories of persons shall be exempt from the requirement to hold an airport transit visa provided for in paragraphs 1 and 2:
>
>    ...
>
>    (c) ***third-country nationals holding a valid visa*** for a Member State which does not take part in the adoption of this Regulation, or for a Member State which does not yet apply the provisions of the Schengen acquis in full, or ***for Canada***, Japan ***or the United States of America***, or holders of a valid visa for one or more of the overseas countries and territories of the Kingdom of the Netherlands (Aruba, Curaçao, Sint Maarten, Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba), ***when travelling to the issuing country or to any other third country***, or when, having used the visa, returning from the issuing country;
>
>    ...

(emphasis added)

The exemption is also reflected on the European Commission's page [Who must apply for a Schengen visa](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en).

The fact that an airport transit visa does not allow you to leave the international zone of an airport follows from its definition in the Schengen Visa Code (Article 2(5)):

> ‘airport transit visa’ means a visa valid for transit through the international transit areas of one or more airports of the Member States;

---

Nineteen hours is a long time to wait in an airport.  It might be worthwhile to try to get a regular Schengen visa to allow you to visit the city, but with a whole family it is also perhaps less likely to be worthwhile than for a single traveler.

The useful site Sleeping in Airports has a helpful [page](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/layovers/things-to-do-on-layover-frankfurt-airport.htm) on Frankfurt noting that it has good options for food, that there are airport lounges with single-visit passes available, and that you can use a shower for a small fee.

They also mention airport tours, but it is not clear whether you would need to be able to clear passport control to book such a tour.  They do mention passport control and security in discussing the option of going to the city, so the tours may indeed be an option for you.  If you find out while you're there, please come back and post an answer.

Finally, there is a transit hotel in case you want to sleep more comfortably than you otherwise would be able to.

A similar [article](https://trip101.com/article/layover-in-frankfurt-airport-what-can-you-do) at trip101.com notes some of the same things, but also mentions that there is a children's play area.

Comment: Good answer.  Just as a note, the play-areas at the airport are only really good for very young kids.

Answer (score 2):

As an Indian citizen, you are exempted **Schengen airport transit visa** (ATV) due to your US and Canada visas.

To enter the Schengen Area (i.e. leave the Airport) you would need a regular Schengen C-Visa.

Since passenger data, on flights to Canada, is shared with the US when flying through US airspace **and** the full details of how these restrictions will be implemented are not yet known (**or** if Canada will follow suit), one should be aware that travel to Canada *may* also be effected under these conditions.

It would be wise to follow the lastest news.

Assume also, that you may not be allowed to use the US-Visa until 14 days after leaving the Schengen Area.

---

**Sources**:

- [Who must apply for a Schengen visa: **Airport transit**](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en)
- [BBC: Coronavirus: Trump suspends travel from Europe to US](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-51846923)
- [Proclamation — Suspension of Entry as Immigrants and Nonimmigrants of Certain Additional Persons Who Pose a Risk of Transmitting 2019 Novel Coronavirus | The White House](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/)

Comment: The OP’s final destination is Toronto, they have a visa for Canada. They mention having a US visa but do not intend to transit in the US, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Traveller This aspect will probably be taken into account when they apply for a Transit visa for Germany. Also the US often forbids persons not allowed entry to use planes flying to Canada using US airspace. At the moment nobody knows how this will be implemented. But without a Transit visa, that the OP needs, they may not be allowed to start their journey.

Comment: So you’re saying that the OP could be refused an ATV even if they have a direct flight Frankfurt>Toronto, in case their flight routes over US airspace? I get the point (possibility of the flight being forced to land in the US, for some reason) but your answer focuses on the US and doesn’t even mention Canada being their final destination.

Comment: @The main questions are: do they need  a transit visa (yes) ; can they leave the airport (no). Due to the changed situation, the issuing of that transit visa *may* be problematic. Without that transit visa, they won't be allowed to land in Frankfurt, thus meationung Canada is really not relevent.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t dispute your visa advice I just think the rest of it is conjecture at the moment, and doesn’t warrant the focus you’ve given it IF (as seems to be the case based on the information in the question), the OP has a direct flight AND a visa to enter Canada. Why not also mention the possibility of Canada following the US lead, or both countries banning entry to those who’ve been in India given that COVID-19 case numbers are rising there? I can’t remember seeing a question about transit on TSE where the final destination is ‘really not relevant’.

Comment: @Traveller Answering the core of the question was the main priority. That the issueing of the needed transit visa may be problematic, secondary. Last year there were reports that Canadian permanent residents, with Muslim citizenship, had problems flying to Toronto where US Airspace was flown over. Flying through Iceland seemed to be needed. So it is known that for the ca. 10 minute flyover New England passenger data is shared with the US.

Comment: Final comment - your answer reads as if the OP’s final destination is the US. I am just asking you to insert a reference to Canada somewhere in it.

Comment: @Traveller you write "I don’t dispute your visa advice," but you should in fact dispute it, because it is wrong.  This answer is incorrect.  The Canadian visa exempts the traveler from the transit visa requirement when traveling to Canada.  The speculation about airspace bans is just speculation, and so far it is incorrect speculation.

Comment: @phoog Indian citizens require a transit visa for Germany based on: **List of third countries whose nationals are required to be in possession of an airport transit visa when passing through the international transit area of airports situated on the territory of one/some Member States (December 2019)**

Comment: @phoog Thanks, yes, thought that too but MJ seemed insistent on the Germany/US angle so it was really that I was referring to. Completely agree that as things currently stand, and with a direct flight between Frankfurt and Canada, the OP doesn’t need a visa and the oft-quoted duplicate question remains the correct answer in this instance.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am well aware of that list.  You are ignoring Schengen visa code Article 3(5)(b) as well as other public information pages on the topic, such as https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en, that reflect the exemption created in that article.

Comment: @MarkJohnson sorry, it's 3(5)(c), not 3(5)(b).

Comment: @phoog How are you reading the Annex 7B (where the exception of 'You may be exempt' are listed) , where a 'X' has been placed? I read it as a **ATV visa is required** (which is the case for India). For CZ Kyrgyzstan the 'X' is crossed out, with the #10  remark: 'The ATV requirement is abolished from 6 December 2019'.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm pretty sure phoog is reading it the same way as you, that an ATV is required for Indian citizens in the general case. But that doesn't matter, because OP's possession of a Canadian visa means they are exempted from that requirement by article 3(5)(c).

Comment: @ChrisH, phoog, Traveler The following is being overlooked: Visa Code Handbook 3.3: A Member State may unilaterally decide to require nationals from certain third countries to hold an airport transit visa when passing through the international transit areas of airports situated on its territory (see Annex 7B).

Comment: @ChrisH is correct.  The fact that India is checked for Germany means that an Indian falls under 3(2) when transiting through Germany.  The fact that *these* Indians have visas for Canada means that they fall under 3(5)(c), and consequently that 3(2) *does not apply to them.*  Mark Johnson: you cite the handbook's section 3.3, but ignore 3.3.1: "The following categories of persons are exempt from the obligation to hold an airport transit visa: ... b) holders of a valid visa issued by ... Canada ..."  I again invite you to consult TIMATIC or other air travel document-checking services.

Comment: @MarkJohnson may I suggest you read the *whole* of Visa Code Handbook 3.3 - specifically 3.3.1, which outlines the same exception as article 3(5)(c).